# How to get the value of the $(this) selector in click or change even

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-selectors

I have already tried this :

```
" document.getElementById("ium_textbox")"
```

but it just can find the first one `ium_textbox.text`

how can I find textbox text in the same `<TR>` :
[image: picture]

Comment: You should use a class instead of an ID. ID is a unique selector. A table has many rows, so there are a lot of IDs

Comment: Have you tried $(this).val(); or document.getElementById("ium_textbox").value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the second input text, then you need to use the class name

**Javascript**

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ium_textbox");
```

**Jquery**

If you want to extract the first input text, then you need to use the class name

```
var value1 = $(".ium_textbox").val();
   alert(value1);
```

If you want to extract the first input text, then you need to use the ID name

```
var value2 = $("#ium_textbox").val();
   alert(value2);
```

Comment: this is my code try to find 
var textbox = $(this).parent().parent().find("td").eq(5).text(); 
console.log(textbox); // but it is empty string


I also tried this 
//var textbox = document.getElementById("ium_textbox");
it is work but only can catch first one ium_textbox

Comment: @Eddy So i that case, You use class name instead of Id
var textbox  = document.getElementsByClassName("ium_textbox");
Hope this helps

Comment: thank you so much 
I found this way to solve it out 
$(this).parent().parent().find("td").eq(5).children("input").val();